# Running a program on every file in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a program that converts docs file to txt file and I would like to apply this code to every file in a directory.

My code is below.

```
for f in ./folder/*; do
    unzip -p $f word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g' >> ./txtfiles/$f.txt
done
```

I would like to redirect the output of the program to `txtfiles` folder.

However I keep getting an error

```
./docs2txt.sh: line 2: ./txtfiles/./folder/docfile.docx.txt: No such file or directory
./docs2txt.sh: line 2: ./txtfiles/$f.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

So for example, in the folder i would have

```
docfile1.docs
docfile2.docs
```

and I want to apply the script and put the output in txtfiles folder as

```
docfile1.txt
docfile2.txt
```

Comment: you can use find with the exec option :)

Comment: @c4f4t0r how do I do that without the overlapping of folder name?

Comment: @c4f4t0r and how do I reference the name of my output file that i want it to be the same as the input file. Only docs becomes txt?

Comment: Try `>> ./txtfiles/$(basename ${f%%.doc}.txt)`

Comment: @jamieguinan ```find ./TRANSCRIPTION/* -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec unzip -p {} word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g' \; >> ./TXT_TRANSCRIPTION/$(basename ${f%%.doc}.txt)``` The full code looks like this? And it's not working

Comment: Try what I suggested in your original example with `for` loop.

Comment: You might need to `mkdir txtfiles` first.

Comment: @jamieguinan I keep getting ```basename: extra operand ‘finance_001_A.docx.txt’
Try 'basename --help' for more information.
./docs2txt.sh: line 2: ./TXT_TRANSCRIPTION/$(basename ${f%%.doc}.txt): Is a directory```

Comment: @jamieguinan I found out that there are files such as ```af_ZA_banking and finance_042_B.docx``` which it's treating it as 3 different files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help debug this, try breaking into a few steps, and use quotes around the filenames that might have spaces in them.

```
for f in ./folder/*; do
    g=$(basename "$f"); echo $g
    g=${g##.doc}.txt; echo $g
    g=txtfiles/${g}; echo $g
    unzip -p "$f" word/document.xml | sed -e 's/<\/w:p>/\n/g; s/<[^>]\{1,\}>//g; s/[^[:print:]\n]\{1,\}//g' >> "$g"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`$f` will return the path that you specified in `for`

for example

```
for f in ./folder/*
```

then `$f` value is `./folder/filename`

```
for f in /tmp/folder/*
```

then `$f` value is `/tmp/folder/filename`

You need to specify the redirect output file according to this.
in your case `>> $f.txt` should work